# Select a Parameter set from Parameter set

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to create a `Parameter set` for my module that has `Parameter Set Names` that change due to `the Validate set` selection that is chosen.

Example

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='All Need')]
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
       ValueFromPipeline=$true,
       ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, 
       ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false, 
       Position=0,
       ParameterSetName='All')]
    [ValidateSet("Selection A","Selection B","Selection C")]
    [String]$1,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
    ParameterSetName='All')]
    [String]$2,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='A')]
    [String]$3,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='B')]
    [String]$4,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='C')]
    [String]$5
)
```

But I have been unable to find a way (for example) to only show Parameter set B if I select Selection B in the validate set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, by using a neat little feature called Dynamic Parameter Set. Read details here:

> [How To Implement Dynamic Parameters in Your PowerShell Functions](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/10/06/implement-dynamic-parameters.aspx)
>
> [How to Declare Dynamic Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/how-to-declare-dynamic-parameters)
>
> This example shows how to define dynamic parameters that are added to
>   the cmdlet at runtime. In this example, the Department parameter is
>   added to the cmdlet whenever the user specifies the Employee switch
>   parameter. For more information about dynamic parameters, see Cmdlet
>   Dynamic Parameters.

and here:

> [Creating Dynamic Sets for ValidateSet](https://vexx32.github.io/2018/11/29/Dynamic-ValidateSet)
>
> [Dynamic Parameters in PowerShell](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/05/29/dynamic-parameters-in-powershell/)

***Simple example:***

```
Function Get-Order 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
      [Parameter(
         Mandatory=$true,
         Position=1,
         HelpMessage="How many cups would you like to purchase?"
      )]
      [int]$cups,

      [Parameter(
         Mandatory=$false,
         Position=2,
         HelpMessage="What would you like to purchase?"
      )]
      [ValidateSet("Lemonade","Water","Tea","Coffee")]
      [string]$product="Lemonade"
   )

   Process 
   {
      $order = @()
      for ($cup = 1; $cup -le $cups; $cup++) {
          $order += "$($cup): A cup of $($product)"
      }
      $order
   }
}
```

So, with that, ***your question could be seen as a duplicate of this StackOverflow Q&A*** that is a longer version of the simple one above.

> [Can I make a parameter set depend on the value of another
>   parameter](http://Start-Process%20'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234176/can-i-make-a-parameter-set-depend-on-the-value-of-another-parameter')

Showing an accepted answer and modification for the final use case by the OP.

```
function New-DynamicParameter
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Core')]    
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)][string] $Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Core')][Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ValidateSet')][type] $Type,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $ParameterSetName = '__AllParameterSets',
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][bool] $Mandatory = $false,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][int] $Position,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][bool] $ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $false,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $HelpMessage,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'ValidateSet')][string[]] $ValidateSet,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'ValidateSet')][bool] $IgnoreCase = $true
    )

    process
    {
        # Define Parameter Attributes
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.ParameterSetName = $ParameterSetName
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $Mandatory
        $ParameterAttribute.Position = $Position
        $ParameterAttribute.ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName
        $ParameterAttribute.HelpMessage = $HelpMessage

        # Define Parameter Validation Options if ValidateSet set was used
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ValidateSet')
        {
            $ParameterValidateSet = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute -ArgumentList $ValidateSet -Strict (!$IgnoreCase)
        }

        # Add Parameter Attributes and ValidateSet to an Attribute Collection
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterValidateSet)

        # Add parameter to parameter list
        $Parameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter -ArgumentList @($Name, $Type, $AttributeCollection)

        # Expose parameter to the namespace
        $ParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
        $ParameterDictionary.Add($Name, $Parameter)
        return $ParameterDictionary
    }
}

function Authenticate
{
  param
  (
    [ValidateSet('WindowsAuthentication','UsernameAndPassword')][string] $AuthenticationType
  )

  DynamicParam
  {
    if ($AuthenticationType -eq 'UsernameAndPassword')
    {
      New-DynamicParameter Username [string] -Mandatory $true
      New-DynamicParameter Password [string] -Mandatory $true
    }
  }
}
```